# How to monitor the successfully execution of tasks in Celery, and call another task automatically, after this execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

The following code call the task `'tasks.task_1'` automatically when we declare the chord object, passing header.

```
header = [current_app.tasks['tasks.task_1'], current_app.tasks['tasks.task_2']]

chord(header)(signature('tasks.task_3'))
```

What I want is **not calling any task automatically**, but just **monitor** the successful execution of some tasks, and after that, call another task (in this case, `tasks.task_3`). How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,